# The toLowerCase() Method appears to not work

Tags: java

I've been writing a program that is supposed to count the occurrence of a letter in a String array. In order to do so I've made every input lower case, so that when the search for the specified letter is being done it is all done in lower case. The program works when the letter being searched for is inputted in lower case, but wont work when in upper case. I'm confused about this because I've used the `toLowerCase()` method to make the inputted letter lower case despite what is inputted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RunStringArray
{

    public static void main (String [] args){

        int arrayLength;
        int count = 0;
        String word;
        String letter;
        int letterCount = 0;
        int x = 0;

        //Asks user for length of array
        Scanner kbInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer");
        arrayLength = kbInput.nextInt();

        //Makes sure array length is a valid number
        while (arrayLength <= 0){
            System.out.println("Invalid input (not positive)");
            System.out.println("Enter a positive integer");
            arrayLength = kbInput.nextInt();
        }
        //Creates array of the user specified length
        String words [] = new String [arrayLength];

        //Asks user to input all strings in the array and makes them lower case.
        kbInput.nextLine();
        while (count < words.length){
            System.out.println("Enter a string");
            word = kbInput.nextLine();
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            words[count] = word;
            count++;
        }

        //Asks user what letter he/she wants to count in the array
        System.out.println("What letter do you want to count?");
        letter = kbInput.nextLine();
        letter.toLowerCase();

        //Error trap making sure the user inputs a letter.
        while (letter.length() > 1){
            System.out.println("Invalid input (not a letter)");
            System.out.println("What latter do you want to count?");
            letter=kbInput.nextLine();
            letter.toLowerCase();
        }


        char c = letter.charAt(0);


        //While loop which will count the occurrence of the letter in each 
        //string in the array, and then adds all of the occurrences together
        //in order to find the total occurrences of the letter.  
        while (count > 0){  
            letterCount = RunStringArray.count(words[count-1], c);
            x += letterCount;       
            count--;
        }

        System.out.println(x);
    } //End of main

    private static int count (String str, char searchLetter){
        int occurrences = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < str.length(); k++){
            if (str.charAt(k) == searchLetter)
            {
                occurrences++;
            } //End of if
        } //End of for loop
        return occurrences;

    } //End of method

} //End of class
```

Comment: Why not `char c = Character.toLowerCase(letter.charAt(0));`?

Comment: Hint that will help both you and us in the future: reduce unrelated code. Dozens of posted lines here have nothing to do with the problem. If you reduce it to just the problem line, the problem might be obvious right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not storing the output of `letter.toLowerCase()`.

Change

```
letter.toLowerCase();
```

to

```
letter = letter.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods that are executed on Strings, Integers, Long etc will produce new objects. Thats why you need to assign those values. The reason: Strings and all those types are immutable, you cannot change its value, when you do java creates new object.

```
letter = kbInput.nextLine().toLowerCase();
```